# Redirect to another page with TOKEN header through Server

Tags: javascript, node.js, redirect

My goal is **redirect to the main page "/"**
but "/" page is attached with Middleware checking user has TOKEN

I want to redirect to "/" **with Bearer TOKEN header**
**WITHOUT AJAX**

So, I made a new path **"/loginDetour" on the server**
and use FETCH to this path with TOKEN Header
then, **"/loginDetour"server** made page **redirect to the "/"**

but....it is not working.. 
Here is my codes

> Main Router

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const hbs = require('express-handlebars');
const path = require('path');
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

const layoutsDir = path.join(__dirname, './views/layouts');
const partialsDir = path.join(__dirname, './views/partials');
const publicPath = path.join(__dirname, './public');

const authRouter = require('./server/routes/authRouter');
const weatherRouter = require('./server/routes/weatherRouter');
const todoRouter = require('./server/routes/todoRouter');

app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
app.engine(
  'hbs',
  hbs({
    extname: 'hbs',
    defaultLayout: 'layout',
    layoutsDir,
    partialsDir,
  })
);
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  app.get('view cache');
}

app.use(express.static(publicPath));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

const checkAuth = require('./server/middleware');
app.use(authRouter.routes);
app.use('/weather', checkAuth, weatherRouter.routes);
app.use('/todo', checkAuth, todoRouter.routes);

app.get('/', checkAuth, (req, res) => {
  res.render('index');
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server started on Port ${PORT}`);
});
```

> Login Router

```
router.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { email, password } = req.body;
    await auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
    const token = await auth.currentUser.getIdToken(true);

    return res.json(token)

  } catch (err) {
    res.status(400).render('login', {
      err: err.message,
      style: 'login',
      isRegister: false,
      type: 'Login',
    });
  }
});

router.get('/loginDetour', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const tokenBearered = req.headers.authorization;
    res.setHeader('Authorization', tokenBearered);
    return res.status(302).redirect('/');
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(400).json({ errMsg: error.message });
  }
});
```

> Middleware

```
const checkAuth = async (req, res, next) => {
if (!req.headers.authorization) {
    return res.redirect('/login');
  }
  const token = req.headers.authorization.split('Bearer ')[1];
  const decoded = await admin.auth().verifyIdToken(token);

  if (!decoded.uid) {
    return res.redirect('/login');
  }
  // const userRecord = await admin.auth().getUser(decoded.uid);
  // console.log(userRecord.toJSON());
  req.uid = decoded.uid;
  next();
};

module.exports = checkAuth;
```

> Front (Login)
> 1.login
> 2.fetch to the POST'/login'
> 3.Server gives TOKEN & Save to the local
> 4.fetch to the GET'/loginDetour' with token header
> 3.Server redirect to the '/'

```
<script type="module">
    import { errAlert } from './js/errAlert.js'
    import { defaultHeader }from './js/auth/auth.js'

    const form = document.querySelector('.login-form')
    const isRegister = {{isRegister}}

    const authHandler = async(e) =>{
        e.preventDefault();
        const email = form['email'].value;
        const password = form['password'].value;
        let userName = ''
        let password2 =''
        if(isRegister){
            userName = form['userName'].value;
            password2 = form['password2'].value;
            if(password !== password2){
                errAlert("Password and Confirmed doesn't matched", 4000)
            }
        }
        const url = isRegister ? '/register' : '/login'
        const config = {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify({ email, password, userName }),
            headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
        };
        const res = await fetch(url, config)
        const token = await res.json()
        if(token){
            localStorage.setItem('token', token)
            const config = {
            method: 'GET',
            redirect: 'follow',
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
            }
            };
            axios('/loginDetour', config)
        }
    }
    form.addEventListener("submit", authHandler)
</script>
```

SOS TTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66594404/how-to-redirect-current-window-location-for-an-axios-get

Comment: The page won't be redirected by ajax requests, instead you will need to check the status of the request and manually follow the redirect. Or better, instead of making a new request to `loginDetour`, just redirect to `/` in the `if (token)` block

Comment: @FredStark I think the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/66595622/441757 isn’t correct. See my comment there: Browsers don’t expose 3xx redirects to your frontend JavaScript code. Instead, browsers automatically follow redirects — so, for example, a condition like `if(response.status === 302)` in frontend JavaScript code will never be reached.

Comment: yeah you're right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was wrong in the comments about being able to read a 3xx response, but if you allow the request to follow the redirects, you can check the `redirected` property and access the final `url`.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/url

Then it's just a matter of doing a client side redirect:

```
  fetch("/loginDetour").then(res => {
    if (res.redirected) window.location = res.url;
  });
```

My first comment still stands however, that unless you need to send the redirect url back from the server, it's much easier to do the redirect after the login request:

```
        const res = await fetch(url, config)
        const token = await res.json()
        if(token){
            localStorage.setItem('token', token)
            window.location = '/';
        }
```

If you have a token, it means that the login was successfull, so just redirect there and save an extra HTTP request.

---

Off topic, but unless you are doing some funky cross-domain stuff, you'll be much better of putting the token in a cookie than `localstorage`.

From: https://balavishnuvj.com/blog/where-to-store-auth-tokens/

> I would recommend storing all long-living tokens (like session ids, refresh tokens) in Cookie with httpOnly and SameSite enabled. As additional security, based on the application and the library/module you are using you can enable CSRF.

and https://twitter.com/ryanflorence/status/1370435079898497025

> Followed a tutorial and put JWTs in localStorage?
>
> If the guy behind UNPKG wanted to, he could inject code to JS requests
> and collect all of your users JWTs. Same w/ any 3rd party scripts you
> use.
>
> 2B req/mo is a lot of tokens.
>
> I put that crap in signed, https, SameSite cookies.

Comment: I appreciate your specific answer ! 
But < window.location = res.url;> solution doesn't work
Because if I use res.url, it requires a token header right in that moment

Comment: Which is why you should use cookies. How else would you allow navigation to `/`?

Comment: Aha . Sorry I misunderstood I'll consider Cookie and Cookie-parser!